# Back end credit card not sending info to PayPal

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

We're running Civi 4.7.4 on Wordpress 4.4.2. We recently switched to PayPal Pro (from Standard) in order to use back end credit cards and keep everything on one site. So far, PayPal Pro has been handling transactions properly from the front end. When I tried to submit something via the back end yesterday (member renewing over the phone) the renew-credit card screen appeared, I filled out the data, and submitted it. The screen refreshed and a new renew-credit card screen appeared and no transaction went through.

Today I decided to do some testing in the back end. None went through. It appears Civi overwrote the test api credentials. I then tried to save the test api credentials again. The credentials were saved, but the "sandbox" portion of the URL was removed. As a result I can't test - everything comes back "internal error internal error." This is occurring when I use an anonymous window as well. What does "internal error internal error" mean? Does Civi show the paypal error code somewhere? Edit: I think I solved this part - it needed a valid mailing address.

I am using credit card = 4111111111111111, CVV 123, expiry Apr 2017, which [seems to be what paypal suggests](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm).

Finally, how do I test a contribution page without overwriting my contact profile? When I click to test as a different person from the logged-in account it appears to send me to a regular version of the contribution page. Edit: using anonymous window here. This part is solved.

I'm at a total loss - I want to be able to test that my payments are going to work when our members try to join or renew, and I would really like to be able to call members as part of our fundraising drive.

Any pointers that can help me get to the bottom of this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of questions wrapped together ;)

As for how to test without overriding your account: either use an anonymous windows so you aren't logged in anymore or add manually cid=0 as an extra param should do it

And to avoid any mistake, you might want to install the no-overrite extension that locks the first and last name :
https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-overwrite

Comment: Thanks for those tips. I have gone the anonymous route for now, but I'm still not making progress. I'll update the above info.

Comment: I think this more or less solves it, actually. After applying these steps and realizing I need a valid mailing address I think I've run enough tests to feel comfortable that this is working, but it would be nice to know why my payment didn't go through last night.